# Why do I have to include the “workstation id” and "application name" attributes in the Database Connection String in order to query a view properly?

Tags: c#, sql-server, view, database-connection, connection-string

At our workplace, we have an ASP.NET application that uses Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Web Edition Database Server for the back-end database.

At first, In the ASP.NET application web.config, I configured the Database Connection String to be:

```
Password=blahPasswordblah;
Persist Security Info=True;
User ID=sa;
Initial Catalog=yadaDatabaseNameyada;
Data Source=blahDNSServerNameblah\yadaSQLServerInstanceNameyada
```

It seemed to connect properly.  However, I noticed something strange when the code in the ASP.NET application would try to query a particular view. The query would return an empty result set.

However, when I changed the connection string to include the workstation id and the application name:

```
Password=blahPasswordblah;
Persist Security Info=True;
User ID=sa;
Initial Catalog=yadaDatabaseNameyada;
Data Source=blahDNSServerNameblah\yadaSQLServerInstanceNameyada;
workstation id=blahWorkStationIDblah;
application name=blahApplicationNameBlah
```

the query on the view in question would return the proper data that I expected.

Here is the metadata about the view:

```
USE yadaDatabaseNameyada;
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS 
WHERE table_name = 'blahViewOfInterestblah'

TABLE_CATALOG
yadaDatabaseNameyada

TABLE_SCHEMA
dbo

TABLE_NAME
blahViewOfInterestblah

VIEW_DEFINITION
Create View dbo.blahViewOfInterestblah ..........

CHECK_OPTION
NONE

IS_UPDATABLE
NO
```

Why does the query on the view in question return the actual proper results when I include the workstation id and the application name in the Database Connection String?

The reason why I’m asking is because when we ultimately deploy the ASP.NET application to production, it would be poor practice to have a “workstation id” attribute and the "application name" attribute in the Database Connection String.

Why won't it work withOut the “workstation id” attribute and the "application name" attribute?

Comment: Do other queries against different database objects require the connection string to have the workstation ID and app name?

Comment: There are quite a lot of database objects ( tables and views), and I've noticed failure to connect with this particular view so far.  However, there may be other database objects that are also returning empty resultsets when I leave out the workstation id and application name attributes.

Comment: Does the view need permissions granted on it? I don't know what the view returns, but it's possible that without specifying those properties, the user context doesn't have access to all the underlying data. Something like how you can query system views, but can't see what's in them without view definition...

Comment: I was also wondering if the view in question had some kind of requirement that would need me to have special permissions to see data associated with said view.  That is why I was querying for info in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS about said view, but I don't see any permission/privilege restrictions.

Comment: If you can query the other database objects without the WSID and app name attributes, then you can narrow down whether it's an issue at the server level (by querying another database), at the database level (by querying another table or view), or at the view level. You should also check to see if you require both the WSID and the app name, or if it is dependent on only one of those attributes.

Answer (score 2):

Though this is an old question, I was looking for info on this very subject, so as a partial answer to this question, and without knowing more about the configuration of the database, server and application user account, here's my brief answer:

According to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/applications/using-connection-string-keywords-with-sql-server-native-client?view=sql-server-2017), both Application (APP) and Workstation ID (WSID) are optional:

> **APP**    Name of the application calling [SQLDriverConnect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client-odbc-api/sqldriverconnect?view=sql-server-2017) (optional). If specified, this value is stored in the master.dbo.sysprocesses column program_name and is returned by [sp_who](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-who-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and the [APP_NAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/app-name-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) functions.
>
> **WSID**   The workstation ID. Typically, this is the network name of the computer on which the application resides (optional). If specified, this value is stored in the master.dbo.sysprocesses column hostname and is returned by [sp_who](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-who-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and the [APP_NAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/app-name-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and the [HOST_NAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/host-name-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function.

Have you tried changing the privileges of the application SQL user or adding them to the DBO role?