# How to include work station id in entity framework database first model connection string dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, connection-string

I have a project that uses entity framework data model(*.edmx*) in it's data layer.I want to add work station id in connection string to store it during create log in database.

This is what I do:

```
var d = new PresentModelConnectionString();
string connectionString = d.Database.Connection.ConnectionString;
string lastCharacter = connectionString.Substring(connectionString.Length - 1, 1);

if (lastCharacter == ";")
{
  connectionString += $"workstation id={Helpers.UserId.ToString()}";
}
else
{
  connectionString += $";workstation id={Helpers.UserId.ToString()}";
}

d.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;

return d;
```

But when it tries to connect to database and get data returns **The login for user sa failed**.When I remove this line:

```
d.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
```

It works fine.

This is the connection string:

```
<add name="PresentModelConnectionString" connectionString="metadata=res://*/PresentModel.csdl|res://*/PresentModel.ssdl|res://*/PresentModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=192.168.1.101\sql2014;initial catalog=MIS;user id=sa;password=sa_123;connect timeout=600000000;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

How can I include work station id dynamically to connection string?

Thanks

Comment: Try `WSID` instead. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45572848/why-do-i-have-to-include-the-workstation-id-and-application-name-attributes and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/applications/using-connection-string-keywords-with-sql-server-native-client?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Alex thanks...I try **WSID** and **WORKSTATION ID** but it still returns login failed.

Comment: What is the value of `d.Database.Connection.ConnectionString;` after you add your id?

Comment: @Alex Sorry for being late, This is the value of that line:                             `data source=192.168.1.101\\sql2014;initial catalog=MIS_Keshavarzi_980906;user id=sa;password=sa_123;connect timeout=600000000;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework;WSID=36378;`

Comment: Try using [SQLConnectionStringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder?view=netframework-4.8), also try `PersistSecurityInfo=true`.

Comment: What happens if you hard-code workstation id in the config file?

Comment: @Alex thank you.I found the solution and post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching several hours I found this solution, it change the connection string of entity framework database first model.As *Alex* recommended in comments I should use **SqlConnectionStringBuilder** to make connection string.

Create a partial class for model context in a separate file for adding constructor that gives connection string as parameter:

```
public partial class PresentModelConnectionString
{
    public PresentModelConnectionString(string connectionString):base(connectionString)
    {

    }
}
```

Make connection string:

```
//connection string in web.config
//Data Source=192.168.1.101\sql2014;Initial Catalog=MIS_Keshavarzi_980906;user id=sa;pwd=sa_123; Connect Timeout=60000;
string connectionString = 
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ABSConnectionString"];

SqlConnectionStringBuilder connectionStringBuilder = new 
SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
connectionStringBuilder.WorkstationID = Helpers.UserId.ToString(); //get work station id
connectionStringBuilder.ApplicationName = "EntityFramework"; //set application name
```

For modifying the model connection string use **EntityConnectionStringBuilder**:

```
EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityConnectionBuilder = new 
EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
entityConnectionBuilder.Metadata = 
"res://*/PresentModel.csdl|res://*/PresentModel.ssdl|res://*/PresentModel.msl";
entityConnectionBuilder.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
entityConnectionBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = 
connectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString;
```

***PresentModel*** should change with your model name.

Finally create a new instance of model context with this connection string:

```
var entityContext = new 
PresentModelConnectionString(entityConnectionBuilder.ConnectionString);
```